# prefix and postfix with dereferencing operator

Tags: c

Why and how is the given code printing `235` in C?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

    char ch[] = { 'z', 'o', 'h', 'o' };

    char *ptr, *str1;
    ptr = ch;
    str1 = ch;
    i = (*ptr-- + ++*str1) - 10;
    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What other value do you expect? Why? What values are the single parts of that expression evaluated to? Did you take operator precedence into account?

Answer (score 2):

In `i=(*ptr-- + ++*str1)-10;`, `*ptr--` is parsed as `*(ptr--)` because postfix `--` binds more tightly than unary `*`.

Since the prior `ptr=ch;` set `ptr` to point to the first element of `ch`, `ptr--` attempts to decrement `ptr` to point before the start of `ch`. The behavior of this is not defined by the C standard.

Since `ptr--` normally evaluates to the value of `ptr` before the decrement, `*ptr--` might produce the value that `ptr` points to, as if it were `*ptr` instead of `*ptr--`. Thus, it would produce the value of `z`. However, due to the incorrect pointer increment, this is not guaranteed by the C standard. Once there is behavior not defined by the standard, none of the other behavior on the same code path is defined.

If we remove the errant `--` and use `(*ptr + ++*str1)-10`, then, by itself, `*ptr` produces the value for `'z'`, which is 122 when the ASCII character set is used. `str1` also points to the first element of `ch`, so `++*str1` increments that element to change it from 122 to 123.

At this point, there is again behavior not defined by the C standard. `*ptr` uses `ch[0]`, and `++*str1` modifies it, and there is no sequencing between the two. By the rule in C 2018 6.5 2, the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard.

If we suppose sequencing is somehow added, so that the increment comes later than `*ptr`, then `++*str1` produces the incremented value, 123.

Then `+` adds 122 and 123 to produce 245, and subtracting 10 produces 235.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression `*ptr––`, postfix `––` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so the expression is *parsed* as `*(ptr––)`; you are dereferencing the *result* of `ptr––`, which yields `'z'` (ASCII 122). As a side effect, `ptr` is decremented and now points outside of the array bounds.

In the expression `++*str`, unary `++` and unary `*` have the same precedence, so the expression is parsed as `++(*str)`, which is the same as `'z' + 1`, or ASCII 123.  `122 + 123 - 10` gives you `235`. As a size effect, `ch[0]` now contains ASCII 123, or `'{'`.

This whole mess is equivalent to writing

```
tmp1 = ptr;
tmp2 = *str;
i = *tmp1 + (tmp2 + 1) - 10;
ptr = ptr - 1;
*str = *str + 1;
```

except that the updates to `i`, `ptr`, and `*str` can happen in any order, even simultaneously.

Comment: The expression has **undefined behavior** for multiple reasons, you should underscore that `*ptr` and `*str` are the same character, hence the side effect `++*str` might modify `*ptr` before it is read or interfere in unpredictable ways... the posted code is not equivalent, it is only a possibility to explain the observed behavior, but undefined behavior removes any guarantee of anything.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate `(*ptr-- + ++*str1)`, the compiler applies the rules of the C grammar: postfix operator bind stronger than prefix operators, they are applied from left to right, then prefix operators are applied to the result from right to left.

`*ptr--` hence applies `*` to the result of `ptr--`, which is the original value of `ptr`, the side effect on `ptr` occurs sometime before the next sequence point, ie the next statement. Since `ptr` has been assigned to the beginning of the array `ch`, `*ptr--` has the value `'z'`.

Note however that decrementing `ptr` before the beginning of the array has undefined behavior... While this particular instance should not cause any problem on most current systems, the mere presence of undefined behavior may let the compiler perform aggressive optimisations with counterintuitive results.

`++*str` is parsed as `++(*str)`: the value is `*str + 1`, hence the next character in the character set after `z`<sup>(*)</sup>, and the value of `*str` is incremented as a side effect sometime before the next sequence point.

This is another instance of undefined behavior because `*ptr` and `*str` refer to the same element of the array `ch`: the side effect on `*str` clearly conflicts with `*ptr` reading the same element. The C Standard describes this as undefined behavior because an object modified in an expression can only be read to compute the modified value, which is not the case here.

The observed behavior, the output of `235`, is consistent with the full expression evaluating to `('z' + ('z' + 1)) - 10` along with unobserved side effects and the use of the ASCII encoding where `'z'` has the value `122`: 122 + 122 + 1 - 10 = 235.

Note that this is only a potential explanation for the observed behavior, but the C Standard does not guarantee this behavior at all: the behavior is **undefined** and the program could behave in different ways: it could output `236`, `329`, `330`, it could stop with or without an error or produce other unpredictable results.

---

<sup>(*) Note that `++(*str)` would also have implementation defined behavior on a hypothetical system where `'z'` would have the value of `CHAR_MAX` with `char` signed by default. This makes `++*str` attempt to convert a value beyond the range of signed type `char`, a situation covered by **6.3.1.3** [...] *Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.* . Many systems have `'z'` with a value of `122` and `CHAR_MAX` set to `127`... close but no cigar:)</sup>